# Searching a multimap in reverse order

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, complexity-theory, multimap

Is there a method for searching a multimap (C/C++ STL) in reverse order in logarithmic complexity ?

Comment: C++ standard template library if you prefer ...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "searching ... in reverse order?"

Comment: Cubbi's point is that there is no STL in C.

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi: by searching in reverse order I mean that, the first element I encounter in the search is the last inserted element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question can be interpreted two ways.  If you mean that you've inserted a bunch of elements with the same key and you want to find the last-inserted element with that key, then you can try `equal_range(key)`, which returns a pair of iterators (one pointing to the first element, the other the last).  However I don't know if `multimap` gives any guarantees about the order in which elements with the same key are stored.

ALternatively, if you mean you want to traverse the `multimap` in reverse order, you can use `rbegin()` and `rend()` to get reverse iterators.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that since a `multimap` is basically a tree representation, the only search mechanism is to traverse the tree - there's no "forward" and "backward".

You can find the first matching element with `lower_bound`, one past the last match with `upper_bound`, or the full range that matches a key with `equal_range`. EDIT: All of these methods run in logarithmic complexity.

Could you go into more detail about what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` as normal but reverse your iteration code.

The last matching element is found with:

```
ub = m.upper_bound(1);
lb = m.lower_bound(1);
if (ub != lb) {
  --ub;
  return ub->second;
}
```

Or with just one lookup:

```
ub = m.upper_bound(1);
if (ub != m.begin()) {
  --ub;
  if (ub->first == 1) {
    return ub->second;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are looking for a search algorithm to locate a key in a `std::multimap`, that

1. guarantees `O(log n)` to locate any key in a `multimap` of `n` keys
2. guarantees `O(1)` to locate the key that is the largest key held by the `multimap`

There is no such thing built-in. Most (all?) multimaps are implemented as balanced trees, and the call to `multimap::find()` tests the middle of the map first, since that's where the root of the tree is. You can see for yourself if you implement a noisy `operator<`.

Would simply testing the key pointed to by `rbegin()` before calling `multimap::find()` satisfy your requirements?

If by "last inserted" you actually meant the element most recently added to the map, then there is no way to find it at all, `multimap` and other associative containers do not retain the information about the order of insertion.

Comment: I'm looking for an equivalent of the multimap::find() that returns the last inserted element. I need only the last element satisfying the condition. When I use equal_range is there an overhead compared to multimap::find() ?

Comment: @Simon.Jacobi: If you are looking for the last element **in order of insertion** that satisfies a condition, `vector`/`deque` may be the better choice. There is no concept of "order of insertion" for maps.